# Route `router` should declare a screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

Пытаюсь скомбинировать Stack Navigator и Tab Navigator. В TabNav должен содержаться стек HomeStack и экран Details. Сам же TabNav находится в стеке StacksOverTabs вместе с другим стеком StartStack. Выходит данная ошибка:

[image: Сообщение об ошибке]

### screens.js

```
import CategoriesList from 'modules/Categories/List/screens/list'
import CategoryPreview from 'modules/Categories/Preview/screens/preview'
import Start from 'modules/Login/screens/start'
import LogIn from 'modules/Login/screens/login'
import SignUp from 'modules/Login/screens/signup'
import Details from 'modules/Categories/Details/screens/details'
import { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: CategoriesList,
    },
    CategoryPreview: {
        screen: CategoryPreview,
    },
});

const TabNav = TabNavigator(
    {
        MainTab: {
            screen: HomeStack,
        },
        Details: {
            screen: Details,
        },
    },
    {
        tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        animationEnabled: false,
        swipeEnabled: false,
    }
);

const StartStack = StackNavigator({
    Start: {
        screen: Start,
    },
    LogIn: {
        screen: LogIn,
    },
    SignUp: {
        screen: SignUp,
    },
});

const StacksOverTabs = StackNavigator({
    Root: {
        screen: TabNav,
    },
    Start: {
        screen: StartStack,
    },
});

export default StacksOverTabs;
```

### index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { StackNavigator, addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { addNavigationListener } from '../redux/configureStore'

import  StacksOverTabs  from './screens'

const RootNavigation = StackNavigator(StacksOverTabs)

const initialState = RootNavigation.router.getStateForAction(
  RootNavigation.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Start')
)
const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const nextState = RootNavigation.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
  return nextState || state
}

const Navigation = props => {
  return (
    <RootNavigation
      navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch: props.dispatch,
        state: props.nav,
        addListener: addNavigationListener,
      })}
    />
  )
}
Navigation.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  nav: PropTypes.object,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nav: state.nav,
})

const NavigationWithState = connect(mapStateToProps)(Navigation)

export { NavigationWithState as Navigation, navReducer }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я изменил в файле

### index.js

```
`const initialState = RootNavigation.router.getStateForAction(
  RootNavigation.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Start')
)`
```

На

```
const initialState =  RootNavigation.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [  NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Start'}),
    ],
}))
```

Больше ошибка не выходит, всё работает